# What are those stuff in C:\WINDOWS\ASSEMBLY\ directory?

Tags: windows

I just came across this directory and it seems totally a different world.

Anyone knows what's that?

Comment: I think this belongs to superuser,not here

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The .NET Framework is an environment (runtime) on top of which code executes. A .NET assembly is a container for code written to execute using the .NET Framework. Assemblies can be either libraries (.dll files) or executables (.exe files).

The .NET Framework has a set of common libraries that can be used by any application which executes under the control of the .NET Framework and the C:\Windows\Assembly folder is where these common libraries are stored.

The reason that the folder displays differently to other folders is because of the special role of this folder as the common location for shared libraries. Microsoft created a special view of this folder that provides easy access to information about the assemblies in that folder as well as providing easy access to operations commonly performed on an assembly such as the Uninstall option in the right-click menu for an assembly.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with assembly language?

Comment: No, as explained above an "assembly" is the name used in the .NET Framework to describe the grouping of related code elements (classes, interfaces) etc in a single file

Comment: Then how to create a **common** view for this folder? Since I know such path exists: C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Management.Automation\1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Management.Auto
mation.dll

Comment: @Lei Yang The special view presented by the Windows Explorer shell is only presented when the folder is accessed using it. You can still use dir at a command prompt to look at the directory as a normal directory. Whether or not you could disable the Explorer view I don't know, though I suspect it may be possible via a registry edit, I've not tried to do this myself.

Answer (score 1):

Using a search engine

> It is used to store .NET assemblies,
>   which can be shared between
>   application.

Comment: What's .NET assemblies??

Comment: I really don't know how to answer this. But regarding your original question please check "http://geekswithblogs.net/pavelka/archive/2006/05/05/WindowsExplorerAndTheGlobalAssemblyCache.aspx" It is basically a folder containing global assembly cache (GAC)

Comment: Does it have anything to do with assembly language?